# cannot tokenize string by space

Tags: android, image-capture

```
  String str ="This is String  {} split() by StringTokenizer, created by mkyong";

  StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str,"\t\n,;{}[]().-<>&^%$@!-+/*~=");
```

I use above code to tokenize.it works fine but not work for spaces

Comment: what exactly is the problem? The words you get they have spaces? and you want to remove spaces in the words?

Comment: i need to split the word by space,{,[] etc

Comment: String.replaceAll("word"," ");

Answer (score 1):

I tried. Add " " at the end. It then seperates by space too.

`StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str,"\t\n,;{}[]().-<>&^%$@!-+/*~= ");`

Comment: if it works could you accept and upvote. it would help others.